# Django Changes in env lib site-packages don't apply

Tags: django, python-venv, django-ckeditor

I meet a problem with a package : django-ckeditor. I have installed it with pip in my venv.
And now I want to add just 1 or 2 modifications in the views file of ckeditor.

The problem is : anything I write in this file:

```
env\Lib\site-packages\ckeditor_uploader\views.py
```

is not applying when I restart server.

Look

```
class ImageUploadView(generic.View):
    http_method_names = ["post"]

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        print("hello")
```

I never get anything when I do this post request.
Actually whatever I write (I removed all the lines and add 'azerrty' in my code) the server will run correctly... Does someone know why changes in my venv are not considered ? And how to solve this ?

I tried to deactivate the venv and activate it again it didn't change anything

Comment: You might need to delete .pyc files from the `__pycache__` directory. But, I would highly recommend not editing third party package source files. Maybe there is some way you can subclass ImageUplaodView to customize it how you want. What will happen when there is a new version of CKEditor? You won't be able to upgrade.

Comment: ok thank you for advice, I will try to create a subclass. But removing the .pyc in the __pycache__ folder didn't change anything :/

Comment: ok that worked perfectly by using ImageUploadView as a subclass! Thank you very much!